# Active Reports 10 Html Viewer Report Source

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, activereports

How can i set the report source for the Active Report Html 5 Viewer so it displays a report i have in my Reports Folder.I have added the necessary references and i have my Report Viewer Showing but i do not see the report.I am using Asp.NET MVC 5.

Html

```
<div id="viewer" style="height:700px">

</div>
```

Javascript

```
    var viewer = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer({
    element: '#viewer',
    report: {
               id: "RdlReport1.rdlx"
           },
reportService: {
    url: '/ActiveReports.ReportService.asmx'
},
    uiType: 'desktop',
    reportLoaded : function () {
        reportsButtons.prop('disabled', false);
    },
    documentLoaded : function(){
        console.log(viewer.pageCount);
    },
    error : function(error)
    {   
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you see? Is there anything in the console (F12). Is the web service called (use the network tab in F12 tools)

Comment: Do any reports function? Have any functioned in the past? Are you certain this tool is installed and running OK? Can you go on to your IIS box and confirm that this URL is valid?

Comment: Tool is installed and running well i see the report viewer but how do i read the Report file to display in the HTML5 Web View?

Answer (score 0):

The id of the report should include the full relative path.

```
report: {
           id: "Reports/RdlReport1.rdlx"
        },
```

Comment: Please check the F12 Developer Tools in the browser to see if anything is getting blocked (404 not found)